# Standard input in dale programming language

Tags: stdin

How can I get in dale the standard input to get data from any file? Thanks in advance.

I've already tried with the "gets" built-in functions. May be I've been doing something wrong.
I need my program reads the given file to get data from them. The script might run from command line. Something like this: "cat sourcefile.lst | dalec myprogram.dt". I apologize for my English and I'm a really beginner as developer.

Answer (score 0):

The [cstdio](https://github.com/tomhrr/dale/blob/master/doc/3-7-cstdio.md) module has the variable [`stdin`](https://github.com/tomhrr/dale/blob/master/doc/3-7-cstdio.md#stdin) you can use:

> `stdin`
>
> Linkage: `extern-c` Type: `(p file)`
>
> The standard input handle.

Comment: Thanks you! I'm trying to get an input from standard input, but stdin function point to a file rather than to the standard input (prompts a user input). I mean, I need to do as follows:  "dalec my_program.dt", then "cat sourcefile.lst | ./a.out" so I could get data by this way and then´print out them to the console.